LWIP UDP Does not work on Raspberry Pi Pico W
I wrote a simple program in C that uses the LWIP udp api to send a message to my udp server running on one computer on my network.
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"

#include "lwip/udp.h"
#include "lwip/pbuf.h"
#include "lwip/ip_addr.h"

#define SSID "MY_SSID"
#define PASSWORD "MY_PASSWORD"

#define SENSOR_PIN 15 // Connected to my motion sensor

int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    gpio_init(SENSOR_PIN);
    gpio_set_dir(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO_IN); // Set pin as input

    // Initialize Wi-Fi
    printf("Initializing Wi-Fi...\n");
    while (cyw43_arch_init())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize CYW43 Wi-Fi module\n");
    }

    cyw43_arch_enable_sta_mode();

    printf("Connecting to Wi-Fi: %s\n", SSID);
    while (cyw43_arch_wifi_connect_timeout_ms(SSID, PASSWORD, CYW43_AUTH_WPA2_AES_PSK, 30000))
    {
        printf("Failed to connect to Wi-Fi\n");
    }
    printf("Connected to Wi-Fi\n");

    // Blink LED to show successful Wi-Fi connection
    cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 1);
    sleep_ms(1000);
    cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 0);
    sleep_ms(1000);

    struct udp_pcb *pcb = udp_new_ip_type(IPADDR_TYPE_V4);
    if (pcb == NULL)
    {
        printf("PCB Could not be allocated.\n");
    }
    ip_set_option(pcb, SOF_BROADCAST);

    ip_addr_t ip_address;
    IP4_ADDR(&ip_address, 192, 168, 2, 11);
    // ipaddr_aton("192.168.2.11", &ip_address);

    const char *message = "Motion detected!";

    while (true)
    {
        if (gpio_get(SENSOR_PIN))
        {
            cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 1);

            struct pbuf *pbuf_struct = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, strlen(message), PBUF_RAM);
            if (!pbuf_struct)
            {
                printf("Failed to allocate pbuf\n");
                continue;
            }

            // Copy the message to the pbuf
            memcpy(pbuf_struct->payload, message, strlen(message));

            // Send the UDP packet
            err_t err = udp_sendto(pcb, pbuf_struct, &ip_address, htons(8085));
            if (err != ERR_OK)
            {
                printf("Failed to send UDP packet: %d\n", err);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("UDP packet sent\n");
            }

            // Free the pbuf
            pbuf_free(pbuf_struct);

            cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 0);

            sleep_ms(10000);
        }
        else
        {
            sleep_ms(150);
        }
    }

    udp_remove(pcb);
    return 0;
}


I tried the code above and its result is: The netcat udp server running on my machine does not get any of the udp packets.
The old error about udb error code -16 has been resolved after following the suggestions.
To run the udp server, I use: nc -u -l -p 8085


I:m not familiar with LwIP but I don't see where you set your server's ip address

I removed it with my WiFi credentials but now it is misleading, I apologize.

Does the device obtain correct IPv4 address after connection? Side notes: You don't check udp_new_ip_type() result. Shouldn't pcb be removed with udp_remove() after usage? Why do you allocate it every time instead of creating just once before loop?

Hello, thank you for your suggestion, I have updated the code and one issue has been resolved. The other one still persists. @dimich

Does Pico W obtain address from the router? What is that address and netmask? Print them to console after cyw43_arch_wifi_connect_timeout_ms(). Is it in the same network as 192.168.2.11? Why ip_set_option(pcb, SOF_BROADCAST) for unicast destination?

Yes it gets the ip address and I can also see it on my wifi settings page. Also yes it is on the same network as the other device

To cut off networking/firewall issues: can you reach you UDP server (nc) from some other device on the network? Can you ping Pico W address from the server if ICMP response enabled in LWIP settings?
